# flink not connect Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-flink

i want to sync data from mysql to es.my code can't connect to es server.here is part of my code

```
                "CREATE TABLE es_alarm (\n" +
                "id  BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT ENFORCED,\n" +
                ") WITH (\n" +
                "       'connector' = 'elasticsearch-7',\n" +
                "       'hosts' = 'https://xx.xx.xx.xx:9200',\n" +
                "       'username' = 'elastic',\n" +
                "       'password' = 'xxxxxxxxx',\n" +
                "       'index' = 'alarmxxxx'\n" +
                ")")
```

but if i change hosts to 'http://localhost:9200',it works

I wonder if the configuration required for HTTPS is different.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in the Flink Jira tickets, there's currently no support for SSL for Elasticsearch in SQL. You can track https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-27054 for progress and more details.